# Are there any examples that show how to apply an InputFilter to a Fieldset?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am creating a module for file uploading which will essentially provide a FieldSet and a view helper to display a widget.

I require a the Fieldset to have a separate InputFilter but I'm struggling to find any functionality in the framework to relate an InputFilter to a Fieldset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement the `InputFilterProviderInterface`. See my example below

```
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class FooFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
   public function __construct() { // add elements }

   public function getInputFilterSpecification()
   {
       return array(
          'elementName' => array(
              'filters' => array(),
              'validators' => array(),
              'properties' => array(),
              'required' => true
          )
       );
   }
}
```

It is absolutely required though that you tell the form to actually validate your fieldset. Personally i do it like this:

```
class BarForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         // other stuff, add elements and fieldset

         $this->setValidationGroup(array(
             'someElement',
             'someFieldset' => array(
                 'fieldSetElement#1',
                 'fieldSetElement#2'
             )
         ));
    }
}
```

If this is too abstract let me know and I'll edit this using a real-world example. Should be enough to get you going though i guess ;)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do that before but without joy. It turned out that I was breaking the framework pattern by instantiating form elements by hand. It appears that getInputFilterSpecification() only gets hooked in if you use the factory (I think). Annoying but makes sense and certainly forces you to do it the 'suggested' way.